# Aligning divs top to bottom and then left to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a main division of width 200px and height 500px. Based on some events I need to add sub divisions of width 50px and height 50px into the main divisions. I need to add it from left Top to bottom and flow towards right.

```
|---------------|
|       |       |   
|   1   |   4   |
|-------|-------|
|       |       |
|   2   |   5   |
|-------|-------|
|       |       |
|   3   |   6   |
|-------|-------|
```

I have tried these CSS, but it is not working.

```
.SubDiv {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background: red;
}

.MainDiv {
   max-height: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background: blue;
   min-width: 100px;
   direction: inherit;
}

<div>
    <div id="SimulationPage">
       <div id = "ParentDiv" class="MainDiv">
       </div>
    </div>

    <input type='button' id = "adddiv" value='add div' />
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#adddiv').bind('click', function (eventargs) {
        $("#ParentDiv").append('<div class="SubDiv"> </div>');
    });
});
```

can some one help me to achieve what i want.

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS-only solution or jQuery+CSS? And how are elements arranged if the user adds (1) two blocks (2) three blocks (3) four blocks... two 50px cannot not fill a 200px wide box.

Comment: Can't you use a table?

Comment: @SalmanA: I am looking for CSS only solution

Comment: @sp00m: no, I do not want to use table.

Comment: @SujithKp : without `jQuery`, you can-not achieve if you have dynamic count of `div`s!!

Answer (score 1):

**What you want to achieve can not be done purely in css because** you have unknown number of child's in the parent class and to float them right-left, you have to find the middle most child and float it from there on.

If jQuery pleases you ( *and since you have tagged this question in it* )

[<kbd>**here is a solution for dynamic count with jQuery**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/FbXzM/13/)

jQuery to use :

```
 var count = $(".MainDiv").children().length; /*get total childs */
    var mid_child = Math.ceil(count / 2) + 1; /* find mid child */
    var x = 1; /*parameter to set negtaive margin, to push right float on top*/
    var current_div_number = mid_child; /* div number to set margin */

    /*assign class name to 2nd half childs, to float them right 
  through css, can be done through jQuery too!!*/
    $(".MainDiv .SubDiv:nth-child(n+" + mid_child + ")").addClass("mid");


    /* check each .mid class and assign negative margin-top*/
    $(".MainDiv .mid").each(function (index) {
        $(".MainDiv .SubDiv:nth-child(" + current_div_number + ")").css('margin-top', -(mid_child * 50) + (50 * x) + 'px');
        x = x + 1;
        current_div_number = current_div_number + 1;
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.MainDiv > div.mid {
    float:right;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .MainDiv {
        max-height: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       width: 200px;
       background: blue;
       min-width: 100px;
       direction: inherit;
    }

    .DivHolder {
        width: 50px;
        height: 150px;
        float: left;
    }

    .SubDiv {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        background: red;
    }
</style>

<div id="SimulationPage">
    <div class="MainDiv">
        <div class="DivHolder" id="Row1"></div>
        <div class="DivHolder" id="Row2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var col = 1;
    var row = 1;
    $('#adddiv').bind('click', function (eventargs) {
        if(row <= 3)
        {
            $("#Row"+col).append('<div class="SubDiv"> </div>');
            row = row + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            col = col + 1;
            row = 1;
            $("#Row"+col).append('<div class="SubDiv"> </div>');
            row = row + 1;
        }       
    });
});
</script>
```

You can the dynamically go and add the DivHolders and add as much as you want

Comment: this approach is good when you already know how many divisions are there. in my case, sub divisions are added as user clicks on the button.

Comment: Is there a limit to the DIV's or is it just to fill your block?

Comment: user can add maximum 6 sub divisions inside the main div.

Comment: And where they go to the left? Is there a limit there?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the dimensions of `MainDiv` and `SubDiv`, you also know number of `SubDiv's` in each column and row. If you are looking for CSS only solution, you can think of using `position`  property. With some hardcoded (less dynamic) CSS classes you can achieve it this way. I have considered `3X3` matrix of `SubDivs`. This is just to suggest you a different approach.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/nwcj5/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="MainDiv">
    <div class="SubDiv">1</div>
    <div class="SubDiv">2</div>
    <div class="SubDiv">3</div>
    <div class="SubDiv">4</div>
    <div class="SubDiv">5</div>
    <div class="SubDiv">6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.SubDiv {
   height: 50px;
   width: 100px;
   background: red;
}
.MainDiv {
   max-height: 200px;
   height: 150px;
   width: 200px;
   background: blue;
   min-width: 100px;
   direction: inherit;
   padding : 3px;
}
.SubDiv:nth-child(4n),.SubDiv:nth-child(4n)+div,.SubDiv:nth-child(4n)+div+div{
    position : relative;
    left : 100px;
    top : -150px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding `float:left;` in the `.SubDiv`